# Keeping MySQL database Synchronized with External Source (.csv) whilst Maintaining Previous Data

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am getting a .csv file uploaded to my FTP server everyday at, let's say 3PM.

For example, let's use this as an example

> population.csv

```
city,population
New York,8008278
Los Angeles,3694825
San Diego,1223405
```

I've converted the CSV file into an array, and used `INSERT INTO` to insert the rows into my table `Populations`

```
╔════╦═════════════╦════════════╦════════╗
║ id ║    city     ║ population ║ status ║
╠════╬═════════════╬════════════╬════════╣
║  1 ║ New York    ║    8008278 ║      1 ║
║  2 ║ Los Angeles ║    3694825 ║      1 ║
║  3 ║ San Diego   ║    1223405 ║      1 ║
╚════╩═════════════╩════════════╩════════╝
```

`id` being an `AUTO INCREMENT` index, and status being a `TINYINT(1)` whose value I am setting to be `1` if it is in the CSV uploaded that day.

Let's say tomorrow at 3PM this CSV file is uploaded to my server:

```
city,population
Los Angeles,3694825
San Diego,1229502
```

As you can see, the `New York` row was not included, and the `population` of `San Diego` has changed.

The outcome I am looking to achieve is for the rows to be updated everyday with the values in the CSV file. If a row is not include that previously was (such as `New York`), I'd like to set the status to `0`.

So the following day, based off the contents of the CSV file, I'd like my database to resolve to something this:

```
╔════╦═════════════╦════════════╦════════╗
║ id ║    city     ║ population ║ status ║
╠════╬═════════════╬════════════╬════════╣
║  1 ║ New York    ║    8008278 ║      0 ║
║  2 ║ Los Angeles ║    3694825 ║      1 ║
║  3 ║ San Diego   ║    1229502 ║      1 ║
╚════╩═════════════╩════════════╩════════╝
```

As of right now, I am using PHP to parse the uploaded CSV file into an array, and additionally a `SELECT` query to parse the database into an array.

Using conditional statements within PHP I am comparing the two arrays for any differences (row value changes, new rows, removed rows).

This is my first time attempting to keep an external source completely syncronized with the contents of the database that have a status of `1`.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this in MySQL itself and not relying on another programming language to construct my statements?

Some ideas that crossed my mind:

- Adding a `LastUpdated` timestamp to each row, if this timestamp falls past 24 hours, create a TRIGGER to set status to `0`
- Create an audit table to reference changes from the previous day. (Deleted Rows, Inserted Rows, etc). After reference, re-insert all unique/indexed values (`id`), and denote a status of 0 to rows that were not included in today's CSV file

Or is my current method of using PHP to compare the CSV to the current records on the table the best way to go about this? As stated, I have some experience with databases, but never tried to do something quite like this. Which direction should I be looking in? Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to first insert the new file to a temporary table, using the LOAD DATA INFILE syntax. The following gives an example, you might need to modify it according to your use case (de [this tutorial for example](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/import-csv-file-mysql-table/)) ;

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/tmp/populations.csv' 
INTO TABLE Temp 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Then, the following query can be used to update existing rows in the main table :

```
UPDATE Populations p
LEFT JOIN Temp t ON p.city = t.city
SET 
    p.population = COALESCE(t.population, p.population),
    p.status = CASE WHEN p.city IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

And this query will insert rows that do not yet exist :

```
INSERT INTO Populations
SELECT p.name, p.population, 1
FROM Temp t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM Populations WHERE name = t.name)
```

Comment: Thank you! Hadn't thought of this before- works as intended.